# Your subordinates make you useless

Tags: work-experience

I am a programmer who has 7-8 years experience and I work in a small (and growing) company, we have hired 5 people till now. Thanks to our hireing process, they are really brilliant, do things really quick, have a decent problem solving approach and have a steep learning curve.

I have been with this company for about 3 years now, and when I joined, there was one other guy who left a year later.

Now with the team growing you have to assign tasks to others, do a breakdown, teach them how to do things and all. And while they do it, they outshine you and in some aspects they can be better than you as well.

So this thing would happen to every senior, I have seen no less than 3 situations where the managers are sitting and doing nothing, are just useless to the company, but then:-

1. Either the company is so big that it doesn't care.
2. They don't pass their knowledge down to their subordinates.
3. They pose their juniors work as done by them.

None of the above applies in my case.

What I can think of:-

1. Look for new dimensions/technologies of work and bring it to your boss.
2. Move towards management, team building, soft skills development.
3. Do some certifications, training.
4. Look for another job.
5. Start my own company.

The problems with the above is that:-

1. I think you cannot be a jack of all trades if you have excelled in
   asp.net you cannot just shift over and be an equal expert in mobile
   apps development for example (All the while we have been taught that
   a programmer knows no language barriers, which I think is not true,
   you need some experience of that particular paradigm to be an
   expert, or to do things professionally).
2. Moving towards management is something I can do, at least my boss thinks like that, but I love to be a programmer, for:-

   a. You can better guide your subordinates if you have really been there and
       done that. 
   b. For better work estimates on new technologies.
3. So i can do certifications but for how long? there will be a limit to the certifications you can do, plus what if your juniors do the same as well?
4. After a span of 3 to 4 years the next job will have the same situation plus I don't want to go through the same process of the transaction from Junior to senior, which is inevitable in the new job as well.
5. This is the only thing in which you are not rendered as someone of any less worth, even if you don't do anything.

So the question:-

**What should a senior person do, if he could do anything, to avoid being someone of any less worth or to be as fruitful to the company as he was when he joined.**

The only answer which I can think of is that this is what happens in the circle of life, people come and go, they get replaced by more energetic, enthusiastic and young people, so I have to live with it. The real losers are those who don't realize this fact and sit in the way of the ones who really deserve the position.

Comment: reason for downvote as well plese

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this suffers a bit from wall-of-text syndrome. Shortening it and focusing it more precisely on your actual question, rather than giving us the full background essay might help. The basic assertion that management is "useless" rather than different is also questionable, unless you're a bad manager. It sounds more like this simply isn't a role you enjoy.

Comment: actually i tried to add in the details what I think of as a solution, so as to avoid the same answers.

Comment: VTC. "*less is more*". Don't add detail but condense this down to a single core question with a short elaboration on your specific situation if you feel that it's required or helpful. You seem to have the completely wrong impression of what management is, how it should be done and how it adds value. Starting with a question like that may get you on the right track and it may actually be answerable. This isn't. That you seem to believe that your reports being better at some things is a problem tells me that you need to rethink some fundamentals.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that you should move into management or get fired. As you said newcomers can do your job for less money and even better !?? not best place to be. I work for a big company, here senior programmers or technicians will get an automatic ticket to streat for reason I posted.

Comment: Well there goes the 20 minutes I spent putting together my answer.  I'm not sure why this was closed, question posed at the bottom of the post seems quite answerable.

Comment: another perspective: https://crew.co/blog/give-your-job-away/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The real losers are those who don't realize this fact and sit in the way of the ones who really deserve the position.

If you have been doing programming for nearly 10 years, you have something none of these juniors have - experience.

You (hopefully?) have experience in multiyear projects. You have experience with understanding customer requirements and working with the business.

A "senior" isn't just a senior because you are older. It's because you have a set of experiences which you can use to add value.

What you are writing feels incredibly victim-like. As if somehow you are the victim of your circumstances - this attitude will cause you to become that way.

> And while they do it, they outshine you and in some aspects they can be better than you as well

This is pretty much the ideal outcome of a senior or manager. Your goal as a senior is to help guide and enable your team to be more awesome. Too many people think that if they train people to be better or more effective than them that it is somehow bad.

**A good manager helps turn normal employees into great employees.** This is the same, but to a lesser degree, for senior employees.

If your subordinates are better than you, learn from them. What a great place to be - surrounded by people who you can learn from!

> What should a senior person do, if he could do anything, to avoid being someone of any less worth or to be as fruitful to the company as he was when he joined.

Figure out what you are good at and get better at it. It's that simple (in theory).

By 10 years into your career you *should* have some sort of skills that are unique because of your experience. Hopefully you have not just been coasting and "getting by" and have skills - maybe project leadership. Maybe mentoring. Maybe technical.

If you can't do that, figure out what you are good at and figure out how to translate that to business benefit. Maybe your company just needs coders and doesn't need an architect or senior. Then maybe your company just isn't a good fit.

Maybe you are really good at relating to a customer. Maybe you should head towards being a BA or product owner or otherwise a customer-requirements role.

It *sounds* like you need to do some soul searching along these lines. Because if you aren't actually more valuable, well, there's nothing you *can* do.

Comment: The big question here is "Do you have 10 years of experience, or do you have 1 year of experience 10 times?". If it's the former, then you do have an advantage over the younger staff members and should be able to provide them with guidance based on your hard earned scars.

Comment: very nicely explained, specially the point that if your subordinates shine that indirectly brings a good name to YOU. And you have to focus on what you are good at. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

> they get replaced by more energetic, enthusiastic and young people

It sounds like you have lost motivation. This is one of the fastest changing industries in the World, I have seen many senior people get lazy and be surpassed, but it's just lack of motivation.

Working life is a competition in some ways, experience trumps everything else if the motivation is there. I actually hire expensive consultants just so I can learn what they know, after which I don't need them anymore, so it's not an age thing.

If you lack motivation or prospects for advancement in your present position, then it's probably time to either coast along or look for a new position. Management has it's own challenges to face but you do lose the 'hands on'. But experienced programmers are in demand in many places, perhaps even contemplate a change of location?

I would not advise you to start a business. Starting your own business is a big risk, and you need to be motivated and energetic if you want to be successful. If you don't go in with that attitude it's a waste of time, because it messes with your chances of ever working for someone else again in a similar position, and the older you get the harder to break back in if you fail. And you're not showing the qualities (no offence) that you would need.